# Recordset not getting updated

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have created a form to allow a user to change their password.

I created a recordset and used edit/update to save it in a query, but the new password is not being saved in the query.

My code is as follows:

```
Private Sub txtNewPass2_AfterUpdate()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("qryUsers", dbOpenDynaset)

    If Me.txtNewPass1 = Me.txtNewPass2 Then

        rst.MoveFirst
        Do Until rst.EOF
        If rst!NName = CboUserName.Column(0) Then
        rst.Edit
        rst!Password = txtNewPass2.Value
        rst.Update
        End If
        rst.MoveNext
        Loop

    DoCmd.Openform("frmLogin")

    Else: MsgBox "Passwords not Matching"

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: the image you posted requires authorization

Answer (score 0):

The expression:

```
DoCmd.Openform("frmLogin")
```

Will result in a syntax error, as the parentheses surrounding the arguments are not required when the value returned by the function is not used.

---

However, you may find it cleaner to simply execute a SQL statement to perform the update, rather than iterating over the recordset, i.e.:

```
Private Sub txtNewPass2_AfterUpdate()
    If txtNewPass1 = txtNewPass2 Then
        With CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", "UPDATE qryUsers SET qryUsers.Password = ?pwd WHERE qryUsers.NName = ?usr")
            .Parameters(0) = txtNewPass2
            .Parameters(1) = CboUserName.Column(0)
            .Execute
        End With
        DoCmd.Openform "frmLogin"
    Else
        MsgBox "Passwords not Matching"
    End If
End Sub
```

Using parameters of course to account for users better known as [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).